# Python for i in range(2,2): print(i) what does i variable contain, it doesn't contain value 2?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to understand how this program works step by step

```
for n in range(2, 10):
    for x in range(2, n):
        if n % x == 0:
            print(n, 'equals', x, '*', n//x)
            break
    else:
        # loop fell through without finding a factor
        print(n, 'is a prime number')

for i in range(2,2):
    print(i)
```

this code doesn't print anything so what's the actual value i contain, does it contains garbage value.

Comment: 1) your indentation is off. please fix it; 2) try `print(list(range(2, 2))`. that might illuminate your issue.

Comment: also, you should add `print` statements immediately below your `for` loops. that'll help you figure this out too.

Comment: This code seems to come from a section of the tutorial meant to illustrate how ’break’ and ’else’ operate in a for loop. For a newcomer that empty list is indeed a little distracting in that context and could have been made more explicit. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

Answer (score 6):

`range(2, 2)` is an empty sequence. Ranges are half-open, so `range(2, 2)` means "all integers `>=2` but `<2`", of which there are none:

```
>>> len(range(2, 2))
0
>>> list(range(2, 2))
[]
```

So, when you iterate it, you get an empty iterator:

```
>>> it = iter(range(2, 2))
>>> next(it)
StopIteration:
```

So, `for i in range(2, 2):` loops 0 times, never even getting as far as assigning anything to `i`, much less `print`ing it.

So `i` contains whatever it happened to contain before this `for` statement:

```
>>> i = 'this is a string'
>>> for i in range(2, 2): pass
>>> print(i)
this is a string
```

… or, if it didn't contain anything, there is no `i` variable:

```
>>> del i
>>> for i in range(2, 2): pass
>>> print(i)
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

Answer (score -2):

for i in range(2,2)  result is empty list []

the code as following:

for n in range(2,11):
    for x in range(2,n):
        if n % x == 0:
            print(n,"prime")
            break
    else:
        print(n,"not a prime")

the result:
2 not a prime
3 not a prime
4 prime
5 not a prime
6 prime
7 not a prime
8 prime
9 prime
10 prime

Comment: There's no code that's building a list anywhere, so how does it result in an empty list?

Comment: Also, what was the point of changing the OP's code to print `not a prime` for prime numbers and `prime` for composite numbers?